# Does asymptotic behavior guarantee uniqueness?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, differential-equations, sp.spectral-theory

Suppose $w$ is a solution of 
$$\frac{d^2}{dx^2}w+\{u(x)+k^2\}w=0$$
with asymptotic condition
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}w(x)e^{ikx}=1$$
and $u\in L^1_1(\mathbb{R})=\{f:\int_\mathbb{R}(1+|x|)|f|dx<\infty\}$, and $k>0$

Is the solution unique?

Comment: Yes. See here for example for some background: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jost_function (the question seems too basic for this site, MSE would have worked better probably)

Comment: @ChristianRemling But here we don't have two boundary conditions. Say we don't have information about the first derivative.

Comment: I assume you mean $x\to+\infty$. Yes, it is unique. The other linearly independent solution will satisfy $\lim_{x\to\infty} w(x)e^{-ikx}=1$.

Comment: Is this question related to inverse problems in some way? If yes, how?

Comment: If $w_1$ and $w_2$ are two solutions you can consider $v:=w_1-w_2$, so an equivalent formulation of the question is: Does there exist a solution to $\ddot v+\{u+k^2\}v+0$ with $v(x)=o(1)$ as $x\to+\infty$? Also, one can assume $k=1$ w.l.o.g., by a linear change of variable.

Comment: @TommiBrander If you agree that inverse scattering problem is a kind of inverse problem, then yes.

Comment: @PietroMajer That's right I also did it. But what's next?

Comment: @DuFong It would be better if you either made the connection to inverse problems clearer, or edited out the tag. As far as I see, the question is about the existence of the forward problem. I would not tag every question about the conductivity equation with inverse problems tag, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under your assumption on the potential, there is indeed such a unique solution,
(I assume you mean $x\to+\infty$ in your boundary condition. This is proved by reducing your differential equation to an integral one, which is solved by the method of successive approximations. See, for example,
V. A. Marchenko, Sturm-Liouville operators and applications,
(Translated from the Russian) Birkhauser 1986.
Chapter 3 Lemma 3.1.1.

Comment: $\infty$ I mean $+\infty$. I read that lemma you mentioned. But it doesn't tell the uniqueness. It only tells the estimation of solution near infinity

Comment: By the same lemma, there exists a solution with asymptotics $w(x)e^{-ikx}\to 1$. Together they form a basis in the space of solutions. Therefore a solution with your asymptotics is unique.

Comment: I see. but Marchenko's lemma requires $w(0)=0$, without this condition do we still have uniqueness?

Comment: @DuFong: I do not see where you found the condition $w(0)=0$ in Lemma 3.1.1. It just says: equation (3.1.1) has a solution such that...